# Iterating nested list, comparing to other list items by looking right instead of down

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.7

I have below nested list called `row_list`:

```py
[
    [{
        'text': 'Page 1, col 1.',
        'top': Decimal('83.640')    
    }],
    [{
        'text': 'Page 1, col 2.',
        'top': Decimal('112.920')
    }],
    [{
        'text': 'Page 1, col 3',
        'top': Decimal('127.560'),
    }]
]
```

Now, I am trying to iterate this list of lists.

However, when I iterate, I want to take each item in the `n` list, and "look" to the right - meaning I want to check in *following* lists (unless it's the last list), that same `n` item's value.

For example, for the first iteration of my list, is below:

```py
[{
   'text': 'Page 1, col 1.',
   'top': Decimal('83.640')    
}]
```

Here I want to check the `top` value of the other `n`item, in the other lists. If that top value is **not** the same (or within a tolerance level of 10), I want to add a new item at the same `n` place - but in the other list.

So following the above example, the top level of `83.640` is not within the accepted range in the other two lists, so we should add an item to each:

```py
[
    [{
        'text': 'Page 1, col 1.',
        'top': Decimal('83.640')    
    }],
    [{
        'text': '', #added item
        'top': Decimal('83.640')
    },{
        'text': 'Page 1, col 2.',
        'top': Decimal('112.920')
    }],
    [{
        'text': '', #added item
        'top': Decimal('83.640')
    },{
        'text': 'Page 1, col 3',
        'top': Decimal('127.560'),
    }]
]
```

I am trying to figure out how to look at lists from left to right instead of top to bottom. This is what I have so far:

```py
for col_no, col in enumerate(row_list):
    #Don't compare the last list, as there are no more lists to compare to.
    if col != row_list[-1]:
        for line in col:
            currentTopValue = line['top']
            nextColValue = row_list[col_no + 1][0]['top']
            if abs(currentTopValue - nextColValue) >= float(10):
                row_list.insert(0, [{'text': '', 'top': currentTopValue}])
```

As you can see, the above is rather static (hardcoded indexes). The row list can have many items within each list.

And for some reason when I execute the code, it doesn't run (seems like it's hanging - maybe a bottleneck?)

Can anyone guide me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this if statement:

```
if col != row_list[-1]:
```

Try build your loop wisely:

```
for col_no, col in enumerate(row_list[:-1]):
```

And your code isn't working, becouse you inserting inside `row_list` new elements during for loop.
There:

```
            row_list.insert(0, [{'text': '', 'top': currentTopValue}])
```

Good way will be create `temp_row_list = []`
And insert this data into this.

It should work, check this:

```
temp_row_list = []
for col_no, col in enumerate(row_list[:-1]):
    for line in col:
        currentTopValue = line['top']
        nextColValue = row_list[col_no + 1][0]['top']
        if abs(currentTopValue - nextColValue) >= float(10):
            temp_row_list.append([{'text': '', 'top': currentTopValue}])
```

Comment: I am a bit unsure about the `[:-1]` part. Doesn't that do so we start at the last item instead? I only want to check the first two lists. I need the values appended/added to my `row_list` - so how do I insert the `{'text': '', 'top': currentTopValue}` into the `n`th position in `row_list`?

Comment: No, this is `list_slices`, what means to avoid last element. Check with this example i sended for you, then try debug this with pythontutor.com or some similary visualization engine :). If you fullfill list this way, they should be ordered in begining order, to reverse u can use that construction: `[::-1]`

Comment: Ah, got it! But still - how do I append the actual `n`th item to the `row_list`? Right now, they are added to `temp_row_list`

Comment: By index assignment you can replace value in list, if u asking about this :). For example: `row_list[col_no][0] = {'text':'', 'top': currentTopValue}` or ingore secound index if you want got list of dicts. Correct me if i understand something wrong :)

Comment: But the value should not be replaced, a new item should be *inserted*  in the list (but at the `n`th place in the list)

Comment: Okay, I now understand, then create `temp_row_list  = deepcopy(row_list)`, iterate over `temp_row_list` with for loop, at the end, add with insert into `row_list`. Now it should work like you want :)

Comment: Do you mind updating your answer to reflect it? I am not sure where to add it and how to use deepcopy?

Comment: `from copy import deepcopy; temp_row_list = deepcopy(row_list); for col_no, col in enumerate(temp_row_list[:-1]):` (...) so on, and insert into row_list: `row_list[col_no][0] = {'text':'', 'top': currentTopValue}`

Answer (score 0):

Because we are modifying sublists adding `dict`s, we want to trace who is the original element; because you're setting `'top'` attribute to `''`, we can search for the first element in sublist that contains some text.

```
def get_elem_for_sublist(sublist: list):
    for elem in sublist:  # dict
        if elem['text'] != '':
            return elem
    return None
```

We then can cycle over the list of lists with a specified tolerance. We can use a counter of current sublist, and at the end of the `while` loop we'll increase it by 1.

Getting index and sublist with enumerate, we can check `if counter_sublist == idx`, getting so the `value_to_compare`, or the current difference between `value` and `value_to_compare` is bigger than `tolerance`.

```
def add_elems(row_list: list, tolerance: Decimal):
    counter_sublist = 0

    while counter_sublist < len(row_list) - 1:
        for idx, sublist in enumerate(row_list[counter_sublist:]):
            actual_idx = idx + counter_sublist

            value = get_elem_for_sublist(sublist)['top']  # decimal

            if actual_idx == counter_sublist:  # get value to compare
                value_to_compare = value
            elif abs(value - value_to_compare) >= tolerance:  # add dict into sublist
                dict_to_add = {
                    'text': '',
                    'top': value_to_compare
                }
                sublist.insert(counter_sublist, dict_to_add)
        counter_sublist += 1

    return row_list
```

Output is

```
[
    {'text': 'Page 1, col 1.', 'top': Decimal('83.640')}
],
[
    {'text': '', 'top': Decimal('83.640')}, 
    {'text': 'Page 1, col 2.', 'top': Decimal('112.920')}
],
[
    {'text': '', 'top': Decimal('83.640')}, 
    {'text': '', 'top': Decimal('112.920')}, 
    {'text': 'Page 1, col 3', 'top': Decimal('127.560')}
]
```

Comment: But this does not insert the `'text': '', 'top': [...]` at the `nth` item. It appends to the list. As you can see in the second list in your example, it's added to the end of the list, whilst it should be at the top (because in the first list, for the first item, the `top` value is not equal to (or within the tolerance) of the first value in the 2nd (or 3rd) list.

Comment: so the first item should be in first position, second in second pos, and so on? if so, this simple edit will do the work for you (instead of `append` I used `insert` at `counter_sublist` position)